# what are the animation formats supported by iphone?

Tags: iphone

i have an flash based animation.but since iphone doesnt support flash.which format can i convert it to other than gif? (gif doesnt support audio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to directly convert it but check out Raphael for javascript / vector animation. It's great! It works on any modern browser including iPhone.

http://raphaeljs.com/

Not sure about the sound part though.